# Required css rule to obtain the required result

Tags: html, css

I am working on a layout which required the result in the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/Kosenshi/a8n52Lkk/

```
<div class="c1">Foo</div><div class="c2">Bar</div><span class="c3">Hello World</span>
```

CSS:

```
.c1, .c2, .c3 {}
```

But the problem is neither I can include additional class nor I can treat three classes separately is there any way to obtain the result.

Thanks

Comment: I think you might want to change the question, as it's pretty unclear what your goal is.

Comment: Something like this http://jsfiddle.net/a8n52Lkk/7/

Comment: @larssy1 my goal is to obtain the result which i have mention in fiddle but i am restricted to write my rule only in the css class body which i have put there so is there any way to write the rule which treat div and span separately and  i cant change the html as you did Pugazh

Comment: and even i dont understand why people down vote my question if no body knows the write answer even though my question is small and clear

Comment: @tayyabrashid You are not allowed to change the CSS rule either?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is exactly what you wanted  try display

```css
div{
    display:inline-block;
}
span{
    display:block;
}
```

```html
<div class="c1">Foo</div><div class="c2">Bar</div><span class="c3">Hello World</span>
```